# A Day at the Races - Head first C#

Tags: c#, random, head

I'm working on C# Lab in Head First C# book.

When I push start button - dogs should run until one of them reach the finish. Each dog should run with random speed, but all of my dogs run with same speed ;/

**Dogs initialization:**

```
 GreyhoundArray[0] = new Greyhound(){
            MyPictureBox = GreyhoundPictureBox1,
            StartingPosition = GreyhoundPictureBox1.Left,
            RacetrackLenght = TrackPictureBox.Width - GreyhoundPictureBox1.Width,
            MyRandom = MyRandom                
        };
        GreyhoundArray[1] = new Greyhound(){
            MyPictureBox = GreyhoundPictureBox2,
            StartingPosition = GreyhoundPictureBox2.Left,
            RacetrackLenght = TrackPictureBox.Width - GreyhoundPictureBox2.Width,
            MyRandom = MyRandom
        };
        GreyhoundArray[2] = new Greyhound(){
            MyPictureBox = GreyhoundPictureBox3,
            StartingPosition = GreyhoundPictureBox3.Left,
            RacetrackLenght = TrackPictureBox.Width - GreyhoundPictureBox3.Width,
            MyRandom = MyRandom
        };
        GreyhoundArray[3] = new Greyhound(){
            MyPictureBox = GreyhoundPictureBox4,
            StartingPosition = GreyhoundPictureBox4.Left,
            RacetrackLenght = TrackPictureBox.Width - GreyhoundPictureBox4.Width,
            MyRandom = MyRandom
        };
```

**Start button code:**

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

**Timer code:**

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (GreyhoundArray[i].Run())
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            else
                timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

**Run method:**

```
public bool Run()
    {
        MyRandom = new Random();

        int distance = MyRandom.Next(1, 5);
        MyPictureBox.Left += distance;

        if(MyPictureBox.Left >= RacetrackLenght)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: While I agree with the *underlying reason* for the problem being the duplicate proposed, it looks like there's already enough support for using a single instance here... so it would be helpful to have a separate answer for that, IMO.

Comment: @jon: As usual I read the stuff you write (or publish) carfully, but I just don't get it: This is simply one more question about why my Randoms are not random at all.

Comment: @TaW: Not obviously, because there's an *attempt* to use the same `Random` each time - see the way that the arrays are being initialized. It's just that that attempt is being foiled by creating a new instance within `Run`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't understand how your underlying answer is any different then the proposed duplicate. Both point to the fact the OP creating a new random instance where the randoms end up being the same. Saying that the OP has already created a single instance in initialization doesn't change the fact that the already provided duplicate will tell him *exactly* what he's doing wrong.

Comment: @Yuval: I think we'll have to agree to differ.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Run` method creates a new instance of `Random()`. I suspect you don't want to do that - after all, you've already *got* a property called `MyRandom` which you're populating when you create the array.

Just take out the line:

```
MyRandom = new Random();
```

and see what happens.

As it is, you're creating a new instance of `Random` every time `Run()` is called... each of which is going to be seeded from the current time. That means if you call `Run` several times in quick succession (on any instance) you'll get the same `distance` most of the time, because the seed will be the same.

Without that extra creation, you'll be using the same instance of `Random` for all greyhounds, which means you'll be generating probably-different numbers for each call to `Next`. This is only okay if it's all in the same thread though - see [my article on `Random`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for details of various tricky aspects to randomness.

Your code already *tries* to do the right thing by setting the `MyRandom` property on initialization - it's just that it then messes it up by overwriting that property in the `Run` method.